# search result not in prioritize order drupal 7

Tags: search, database

Hi i am new to drupal 7 and also to sql query builder format.i have a requirement to search the string. in that **i hav to display exact matched string at the top followed by related matches**. i explode a string with space and searched a each word exist or not.the code as follows.

$keys -> contain the search term

```
 $keys = preg_replace('!\*+!', '%', $keys);

$keys = explode(' ', trim(str_replace(array( '\'', '"', ',' , ';', '<', '>','!','_','-','+','@','#','$','%','^','&','.'), ' ', $keys)));;

 $query = db_select('file')->extend('PagerDefault');
 $query->fields('file', array('fid','filename'))
  ->fields('fs', array('e_id','f_subtitle_value'));

 $subquery = db_select('field_data_sub','fs');
 $subquery->Fields('fs', array('e_id','f_subtitle_value'));
 $subquery->condition('fs.e_type', 'node','!=');

 $query->leftjoin($subquery,'fs','file.fid = fs.e_id');
 $db_or = db_or();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
if(!(empty($key))) {
 $db_or->condition('filename', "%$key%", 'LIKE');
 }
}

$query->condition($db_or); 
  $query->condition(db_and()->
          condition('filemime', 'image/jpeg', '!=')->
           condition('filemime', 'image/png', '!='));
```

i tried union all - wrote two query and combine it.. it fetches output but the exact searched result came twice . is that a gud way or else is there any other way.. please suggest the best way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use default drupal's search from admin/config/search/settings and se [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) for searching specific fields. You need not write any code or Query to search in a Drupal site unless it is needed.

Comment: it is the custom module. the module is already created and i need to search the value in custom module's table. pls help me.